# How do I get a persistent mount between boots?

Tags: 12.04, automount

I guess I should start with what I've got and where I am now:

1. I added a (true) hardware raid 5 array to my 12.04 install (on a separate disk)
2. I chose to format the 4 TB volume w/o any partitioning. (I suspect this may be the source of my problems)
3. the volume (named raid5) shows up in nautilus at the top of the left panel. Under properties - location is - `/media`
4. I used `blkid` to copy & paste UUID into `/etc/fstab`.

   ```
   UUID=4be9f4bd-5666-4c21-8715-5d2a866fd840 /media/Raid5    ext4      0   0
   ```

I can mount from nautilus and from terminal. But, after reboot the volume is not mounted. The fstab edit seems to have had no effect.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the options field (the 4th) is missing, it should be something like this:

```
UUID=4be9f4bd-5666-4c21-8715-5d2a866fd840 /media/Raid5    ext4  auto  0   0
```